# docker image [solanalabs/solana]

Tags: solana-cli

I'm trying to use docker image `solanalabs/solana` to install CLIs like Solana CLI or Sugar CLI.
I tried `docker run -it --name solana solanalabs/solana:stable bash` but the status got exited immediately.
What should I do to go inside the container and execute commands?

[solana docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/solanalabs/solana)